# Can a parser fail silently?

Tags: antlr

May ANTLR generated parsers fail *silently*? That
is, can they omit diagnosing when not recognising?

Using a very small grammar for a demonstration and using defaults only for ANTLR, these are the contrasting observations:

When sending input to the usual test rig for the grammar below, I am
noticing two things:

1. the parsers recognize valid input (actions show that), o.K.;
2. **however**, the recognisers seem to “accept” certain invalid(?) inputs, meaning there is no
   diagnosis. V3 and v4 parsers behave similarly. The issue—if there is
   an issue—appears when there are characters (`'1'`) missing
   at the front of an input for `stat`, provided that prior to this input another input of
   just a NEWLINE had been sent.

This is the v4 grammar:

```
grammar Simp;

prog : stat+ ;
stat : '1' '+' '1' NEWLINE 
     | NEWLINE
     ;

NEWLINE : [\r]?[\n] ;
```

The v3 grammar is the same, mutatis mutandis.

Some runs using v4; class *TestSimp4* is the usual test rig as in the book(s),
see below:

```bash
% printf "1+1\n" |java -classpath "antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar:." TestSimp4
% printf "+1\n" |java -classpath "antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar:." TestSimp4 
line 1:0 extraneous input '+' expecting {'1', NEWLINE}
line 1:2 mismatched input '\n' expecting '+'
% printf "\n+1\n" |java -classpath "antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar:." TestSimp4
%
```

The first two invocations' results I had expected. I had expected the last invocation to visibly **fail**, though. Correct?

Looking at the generated *SimpParser.java*, the silent exit seems
consequential, as outlined below. But should it be that way? I am thinking that ANTLR just
stops before recognising invalid input here, but it shouldn't just stop.

**Question**: Is this silent failure rather to be expected? Have I
overlooked something like a greedyness setting for grammar tokens with a
`+` suffix?

### Some code analysis.

Referring to the loop that calls `stat()` (in the
`prog()` procedure):

> The v3 parser sets a counter variable to >= 1 on sucessfully matching
> the initial `NEWLINE`. The effect is that *EarlyExitException* is then
> *not* being thrown on later inputs, it just `break`s the loop.

> The v4 parser similarly calls `_input.LA(1)` and then just terminates
> the loop whenever that call’s result cannot be at the start of `stat`.
> (So no recovery?)

The test rig:

```java
class TestSimp4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final CharStream subject   = CharStreams.fromStream(System.in);
    final TokenSource tknzr    = new SimpLexer(subject);
    final CommonTokenStream ts = new CommonTokenStream(tknzr);
    final SimpParser parser    = new SimpParser(ts);
    parser.prog();
  }
}
```

So another paraphrase of my question would be: “How does one
create ANTLR parsers such that they will always say YES or NO?”

Comment: Always use an EOF-terminated rule (see Bart's answer). Always print out your tokens and parse tree. Always write custom ErrorListeners to check for both lexer and parser. Lexer does not have a ["_syntaxErrors"](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.html#_syntaxErrors) count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 3rd test input, `\n+1\n`, does not produce an error because you're telling it to recognize the production/rule `stat` once or more. And `prog` successfully matches the input `\n` and then stops. If you want the entire input (token stream) to be consumed, "anchor" your `prog` rule with the EOF token:

```
prog : stat+ EOF;
```